# Ksoap2 Base64binary and Complex Data

Tags: android, ksoap2

Hello im a student and im trying to implement android fingerprint application. I need to pass values to webservice but i couldnt do that.

Here Xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <GetKisiYetkiBilgiByBioInfo xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <bioTemplate>base64Binary</bioTemplate>
      <sGecis>
        <GecisID>long</GecisID>
        <KisiID>long</KisiID>
        <GecisNoktasiID>int</GecisNoktasiID>
        <GecisTurID>int</GecisTurID>
        <Tarih>dateTime</Tarih>
        <TarihBilgisi>string</TarihBilgisi>
        <AdiSoyadi>string</AdiSoyadi>
        <GecisNoktasiAdi>string</GecisNoktasiAdi>
        <GecisTuruAdi>string</GecisTuruAdi>
        <Limit>double</Limit>
        <ElleMudahale>boolean</ElleMudahale>
        <YemekErtelemeUrunBazli>boolean</YemekErtelemeUrunBazli>
        <TimeLog>string</TimeLog>
        <ReferenceID>string</ReferenceID>
      </sGecis>
      <bioTemplateType>FingerPrintByNeuroTech or FingerPrintByNEC or FaceByNEC or FaceByNeuroTech or FingerVeinByNEC or FingerImage</bioTemplateType>
    </GetKisiYetkiBilgiByBioInfo>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

When i request i get Soap fault: The specified type was not recognized: name='sGecis' can anyone help me.

Here My Code (I have sGecis class and marshal classes)

```
public static String GirisYetki(byte[] Image,String webMethName) {
            String resTxt = null;
            // Create request
            SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, webMethName);

            request.addProperty("sGecis", sGecis);
            request.addProperty("bioTemplate", Image);

            request.addProperty("bioTemplateType", "FingerImage");



            // Create envelope
            SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                    SoapEnvelope.VER11);
            //Set envelope as dotNet
            envelope.dotNet = true;
            // Set output SOAP object            
            envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

            MarshalDouble mdouble = new MarshalDouble();
            mdouble.register(envelope);
            MarshalDate md = new MarshalDate();
            md.register(envelope);
            envelope.addMapping(NAMESPACE, "sGecis",new sGecis().getClass());
            // Create HTTP call object

            HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

            try {
               // Invoke web service
                androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION+webMethName, envelope);
                // Get the response
                Girisresult = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();
                resTxt=Girisresult.toString();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                //Print error
                e.printStackTrace();
                resTxt= resTxt + e.getMessage();
            } 
            //Return resTxt to calling object
            return resTxt;
        }
```

Soap Fault

```
SoapFault - faultcode: 'soap:Client' faultstring: 'System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to read request. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: There is an error in XML document (334, 36). ---> System.InvalidOperationException: The specified type was not recognized: name=':', namespace='http://tempuri.org/', at <sGecis xmlns='http://tempuri.org/'>.
   at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReader1.Read18_SGecis(Boolean isNullable, Boolean checkType)
   at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReader1.Read72_GetKisiYetkiBilgiByBioInfo()
   at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.ArrayOfObjectSerializer64.Deserialize(XmlSerializationReader reader)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(XmlReader xmlReader, String encodingStyle, XmlDeserializationEvents events)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(XmlReader xmlReader, String encodingStyle, XmlDeserializationEvents events)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(XmlReader xmlReader, String encodingStyle)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapServerProtocol.ReadParameters()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapServerProtocol.ReadParameters()
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandler.CoreProcessRequest()' faultactor: 'null' detail: org.kxml2.kdom.Node@4319ef50
```

Comment: Try using kvm serialization http://seesharpgears.blogspot.de/2010/10/ksoap-android-web-service-tutorial-with.html

Comment: Ty Remees i did serialization already sGecis as KVMSerialization but i couldnt marshal date , double, and base64 binary